# Without using an Empty, how is it possible to have an object bend on the Y (or X) world axis using the Simple Deform modifier?

Tags: modifiers

I am trying to understand how the Simple Deform / Bend modifier works. I understand that the Bend modifier only works around the Z axis. What I am trying to figure out is how to have an object bend around the Y (or X) axis without having to use an Empty.

I found an example of what I am trying to accomplish here:
http://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?350541-MotionTool-Dev-Thread/page2 and the direct link to the blend file is https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/2086432/Motion_Tool_Testing.zip

The object "Deelis" (in the plank.blend file) is bending on the Y axis with no empty when the Simple Deform>Deform>Angle is changed. How is this possible? I can't figure out how to reproduce this.

Thanks,
Bryson

Comment: It bends **over** its local Z axis, **along** its local Y axis.

Comment: Thanks. I was doing my rotation in Edit Mode and Object Mode was what I needed to rotate it in to achieve the desired result....long day :)

Comment: I had troubles with that modifier too, but I think I've got the hang of it. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. In Object Mode, rotate the plank on its side by -90 degrees in the X axis, freeze rotation and then rotate it 90 degrees in the X axis again.